# Add Rows After Populating a Dialog Box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, modal-dialog

I have an HTML table and I want to be able to add a row after I click a button and a dialog box pops up where I can type in the necessary row information. I came across some code that does exactly what I want. I tailored it to go with my code as much as I could. So far, I have the popup box, but it does not add a row after I click "add row" in the popup which is what I need it to do. I was hoping someone might be able to tell me what is wrong with this. I'm pretty stuck on it.

JavaScript:

```
// ----- Dialog Box -----

$( function() {
    var dialog, form,

      emailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/,
      mr_name = $( "#mr_name" ),
      buyer_id = $( "#buyer_id" ),
      poc_n = $( "#poc_n" ),
      poc_e = $( "#poc_e" ),
      poc_p = $( "#poc_p" ),
      allFields = $( [] ).add( mr_name ).add( buyer_id ).add( poc_n ).add( poc_e ).add( poc_p ),
      tips = $( ".validateTips" );

    function updateTips( t ) {
      tips
        .text( t )
        .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
      setTimeout(function() {
        tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );
      }, 500 );
    }

    function checkLength( o, n, min, max ) {
      if ( o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min ) {
        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
        updateTips( "Length of " + n + " must be between " +
          min + " and " + max + "." );
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }

    function checkRegexp( o, regexp, n ) {
      if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) {
        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
        updateTips( n );
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }

    function addVendor() {
      var valid = true;
      allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );

      valid = valid && checkLength( mr_name, "mr_id", 3, 16 );
      valid = valid && checkLength( buyer_id, "buyer_id", 6, 80 );
      valid = valid && checkLength( poc_n, "poc_n", 5, 16 );
      valid = valid && checkLength( poc_e, "buyer_id", 6, 80 );
      valid = valid && checkLength( poc_p, "poc_n", 5, 16 );

      valid = valid && checkRegexp( mr_id, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_\s])+$/i, "Username may consist of a-z, 0-9, underscores, spaces and must begin with a letter." );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( buyer_id, /^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/, "Password field only allow : a-z 0-9" );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( poc_n, /^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/, "Password field only allow : a-z 0-9" );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( poc_e, emailRegex, "eg. ui@jquery.com" );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( poc_p, /^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/, "Password field only allow : a-z 0-9" );

      if ( valid ) {
        $( "#html_master tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
          "<td>" + mr_name.val() + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + buyer_id.val() + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + poc_n.val() + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + poc_e.val() + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + poc_p.val() + "</td>" +
        "</tr>" );
        dialog.dialog( "close" );
      }
      return valid;
    }

    var dialog = $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 400,
      width: 350,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Add Row": addVendor,
        Cancel: function() {
          dialog.dialog( "close" );
        }
      },
      close: function() {
        form[ 0 ].reset();
        allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
      }
    });

    form = dialog.find( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      addVendor();
    });

    $( "#create-user" ).button().on( "click", function() {
      dialog.dialog( "open" );
    });
  } );
```

HTML/PHP:

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test1.css">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="test1.js"></script>
    </head>

<body>

<div id="dialog-form" title="Add Vendor">
  <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>

  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <label for="mr_id">Vendor</label>
      <input type="text" name="mr_id" id="mr_id" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
      <label for="buyer_id">Buyer ID</label>
      <input type="text" name="buyer_id" id="buyer_id" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
      <label for="poc_n">POC Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="poc_n" id="poc_n" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
      <label for="poc_p">POC Email</label>
      <input type="text" name="poc_e" id="poc_e" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
      <label for="poc_p">POC Phone</label>
      <input type="text" name="poc_p" id="poc_p" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">

      <!-- Allow form submission with keyboard without duplicating the dialog button -->
      <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>



<div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget">
<table id="html_master" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
<thead>
    <tr class="ui-widget-header">
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Vendor</td>
    <td>Buyer ID</td>
    <td>POC Name</td>
    <td>POC Email</td>
    <td>POC Phone</td>
    <td>Edit/Delete</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<?php
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $rows){
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="mr_id" contenteditable="false"><?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?></td>
        <td class="mr_name" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_Name']?></td>
        <td class="buyer_id" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['Buyer_ID']?></td>
        <td class="poc_n" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_N']?></td>     
        <td class="poc_e" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_E']?></td>
        <td class="poc_p" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_P']?></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="edit" name="edit" value="Edit">
        <input type="button" class="deactivate" name="deactivate" value="Deactivate"></td>
    </tr>
 <?php
  }
 ?>
</tbody>

</table>
</div>

        <input type="button" id="create-user" value="Add Row">

</body>  
</html>
```

I know the validation is off right now, but that is not my current focus. I just want to be able to add a row after I populate the pop up window.

Comment: Seeing your current code, I'd presume the row is added to the table as expected, but when you reload the page these rows disappear. Is this what happens?

Comment: You are correct in that the rows disappear upon reload as I have not written them to a DB yet...however, it does not add rows either...when the popup box is up and I type in the info and click "add row" nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I placed your code in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/92/), removing the PHP part, to debug it better. One thing I'm not sure you know, though it's very useful, is that you can use the browser's console (right-button click > Inspect > Console) to look for eventual JS errors.

Anyway, nothing was happening when you clicked `Add Row` because there was a few errors in your script.

1) This line: `mr_name = $( "#mr_name" ),` should be `mr_name = $( "#mr_id" ),`, since `mr_id` is the `id` you gave to your HTML input

2) This line: `valid = valid && checkRegexp( mr_id, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_\s])+$/i, "Username may consist of a-z, 0-9, underscores, spaces and must begin with a letter." );` should have `mr_name` instead of `mr_id`, since it's the variable you named in the line I mentioned in the previous item

Comment: This is exactly what I needed...thank you very much!!